# Flutter: Pushing to GitHub from Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, github, gitignore

[Screenshot of greyed out lib folder and dart files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkt0V.png)

Hi there, has anyone else encountered the issues where the lib file is greyed out in visual studio code, and all other dart files inside are greyed out as well?

It seems to cause an issue when pushing the files to GitHub with the GitHub desktop app. I have tried looking at the .gitignore file, but I have not been able to solve the issue.

Anyone managed to solve this issue?

I have tried changing the name of the file from 'lib' to 'library', and the folder was no longer greyed out. However, doing so caused the code to crash and I have changed it back to 'lib' for the time being.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_git-status-in-file-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error, it will be automatically grayed out when you add and commit the files in GitHub.

There are some green indicators that are indicating that either you have add those files in your local git but didn't commit yet, or you have created new files that aren't tracking by Git. When you add those files to your Git repository and commit it, all the files will be grayed out.

Comment: I understand that the files would be greyed out when these files have been committed to github. However, even after editing these files locally, the entire folder, and the file that I have edited is still greyed out. When viewed from github desktop, the changes i made in these files are not reflected and the file does not get pushed.

Comment: Did you tried pushing from vs code instead of Github deskop?

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I finally managed to track the file by pushing from vscode instead of GitHub Desktop.